# Provision a an on-demand node for aws eks cluster ... Node is failing to join cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, karpenter

I'm attempting to utilize Karpenter to provision a transient node for a short-lived pod in Amazon EKS. I've followed the steps outlined in the Karpenter documentation (https://karpenter.sh/docs/getting-started/) and managed to set up most of the configuration. However, upon applying the deployment, the node starts up but then promptly terminates due to an error:

"Client.InvalidKMSKey.InvalidState: The KMS key provided is in an incorrect state."

Even after granting all the necessary KMS key permissions to the Karpenter node role, the issue persists. I'm at a loss for how to proceed. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a Key policy as well in addition to IAM policy for the instance role?